# RoutingError (No route matches [PUT]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

Im having an issue with regard my routes. Im using devise but I also have custom controllers to allow admins to edit user settings.

In my case, everything works fine in development but when i deploy to my hosting server things dont work as they should.

Problem i have is as follows, when an admin updates a user, i get a routing error. This works fine locally but on the hosting server i get the following

```
Started PUT "/users/4"  at Fri Feb 21 04:08:14 -0500 2014
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/4"):
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'>  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
```

What doesnt look right to me, is how the "/users/4" gets stripped down to "/4". What happened to the rest of the path?

My routes look fine

```
users POST   /users(.:format) users/registrations#create
      new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                 devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)             devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)            devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                   users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                          users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                  users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                     users/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                          users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                          users/registrations#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#new
                         POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                 devise/sessions#destroy
                         POST   /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#create
                         GET    /users/password/new(.:format)             devise/passwords#new
                         GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)            devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
                         GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                   devise/registrations#cancel
                         POST   /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#create
                         GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                  devise/registrations#new
                         GET    /users/edit(.:format)                     devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#destroy
                         GET    /users(.:format)                          users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                          users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                      users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                 users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                      users#destroy
```

As you can see the user update path exists

> PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#update

The host server is using passenger, rails 3.2.X, ruby 1.8.7. I´m aware there is security issues with the 3.2.x version but this is just a hobby of mine.

Routes config

```
resources :comm_channels

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" } do
  post '/users', :to => 'users/registrations#create'
end

devise_for :users

resources :users,:roles,:news ,:invites, :clubs, :events, :albums, :pictures, :static_pages, :sponsors

match "static_pages/:action/:pagetype", :controller => "static_pages"
match 'invites/edit(/:eid/:iid/:code)' => 'invites#edit', :as => :invite_confirm
match 'events/:id/reminder' => 'events#reminder', :as => :event_reminder
match 'events/:id/republish' => 'events#republish', :as => :event_republish
match 'roles/resetMembership' => 'roles#resetMembership', :as => :reset_membership
match 'roles/membership_reminder' => 'roles#membership_reminder', :as => :membership_reminder

root :to => "static_pages#show#home"
```

***Update 2***

Ive taken Tims comments on board and cleaned up my routes file however im still seeing the same issue.

My routes now look like

```
resources :comm_channels

devise_for :users,:path => 'club_users', :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" } do
  post '/users', :to => 'users/registrations#create'
end


resources :users

resources :roles,:news ,:invites, :clubs, :events, :albums, :pictures, :static_pages, :sponsors

match "static_pages/:action/:pagetype", :controller => "static_pages"
match 'invites/edit(/:eid/:iid/:code)' => 'invites#edit', :as => :invite_confirm
match 'events/:id/reminder' => 'events#reminder', :as => :event_reminder
match 'events/:id/republish' => 'events#republish', :as => :event_republish
match 'roles/resetMembership' => 'roles#resetMembership', :as => :reset_membership
match 'roles/membership_reminder' => 'roles#membership_reminder', :as => :membership_reminder

root :to => "static_pages#show#home"
```

Routes output is as follows

```
        users POST   /users(.:format)                          users/registrations#create
        new_user_session GET    /club_users/sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /club_users/sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /club_users/sign_out(.:format)            devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /club_users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /club_users/password/new(.:format)        devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /club_users/password/edit(.:format)       devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /club_users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /club_users/cancel(.:format)              users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /club_users(.:format)                     users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /club_users/sign_up(.:format)             users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /club_users/edit(.:format)                users/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /club_users(.:format)                     users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /club_users(.:format)                     users/registrations#destroy
                         GET    /users(.:format)                          users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                          users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                      users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                 users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                      users#destroy
```

I still see the same error in production setup.

```
Started PUT "/users/21" for 194.XXXX at Sun May 11 08:05:48 -0400 2014

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/21"):
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:61:in `call'
```

ive tried different also the simplest variation e.g

```
devise_for :users,:path => 'club_users'
resources :users
```

And also the reverse

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, :path => 'useradmin'
```

No joy. As I said before rake routes tells me its there

```
PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#update
```

but somewhere along the line, PUT "/users/21" gets stripped down to "/21".

Any ideas?

Comment: please add your /config/routes.rb

Comment: Routes have been added.

Comment: Hm, I have no clue and I don't remember I ever encountered this behaviour. Maybe somebody else has any idea. Please check if it occurs for other routes as well or only `put users`. Locally you run webrick or thin or something like that?

Comment: Locally i use webrick. I dont have any issues with any of the other models, creating and updating events/news are no problem.

Comment: I suppose if it had something to do with production setup for example passenger configuration then it should consistently rewrite the url. If you not already have, can you start your app locally in production env `rails s -e production` and have a look if this behaves the same?

Comment: And if it is definitly no typo by accident on the edit users page or wherever you build the request to put users than you may look into devise and how you use it.

Comment: Ran locally in prod mode, Works fine  Started PUT "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Feb 21 14:18:59 +0100 2014
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML

Comment: hm² ...then I am out of ideas for now. Can you add the controller as well? Relevant parts should only be class line, filters and update action and everything that is used by these...Have you had a look into your production source code if it is based on the same commit/source?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain why just that particular route is giving you trouble and only in production, but I think there are some general issues with your routes which if you fix, will probably resolve the problem with that particular route.

Firstly, you have:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" } do
  post '/users', :to => 'users/registrations#create'
end

devise_for :users
```

As you can see from your routes, this repetition of `devise_for` has resulted in most of your routes being duplicates except for the registration routes for which there are two copies of each route; half of them go to your overridden registrations controller (because of the first `devise_for`) and half of them go to devise's registrations controller (because of the second `devise_for`.  You should only have one `devise_for`.  Which one you keep depends on which registration controller you want to be used by people who are registering.  Assuming you want them to use your overridden version, you should remove the second `devise_for`.  Also, in the first `devise_for`, I think you can remove the `post` line as that is the default that you would get anyway.

Once you've done this, you'll have one set of devise routes as well as your other user routes (from `resources :users`).  However, you still have a problem; you still have:

```
user_registration POST   /users(.:format)    users/registrations#create
```

from the `devise_for`, and:

```
                  POST   /users(.:format)    users#create
```

because of the `resources :users`.  The same http method and path is mapped to different controllers, which isn't going to work.  I suggest you give your users controller a different path to keep a clean separation between the work of registering and login etc. (devise) and your user management controller.  Instead of:

```
resources :users,:roles,:news ,:invites, :clubs, :events, :albums, :pictures, :static_pages, :sponsors
```

try this:

```
resources :users, :path => 'useradmin'
resources :roles, :news, :invites, :clubs, :events, :albums, :pictures, :static_pages, :sponsors
```

or whatever appropriate pathname you want instead of `useradmin`.  This will only change the path; it'll keep the route helpers and expected controller name the same, so you should then have:

```
            new_user GET    /useradmin/new(.:format)                      users#new
           edit_user GET    /useradmin/:id/edit(.:format)                 users#edit
                user GET    /useradmin/:id(.:format)                      users#show
                     PUT    /useradmin/:id(.:format)                      users#update
                     DELETE /useradmin/:id(.:format)                      users#destroy
```

Or you can do the opposite; keep your user controller at /users and map the devise controllers to another path using `:path => 'whatever-you-want'` as a parameter to `devise_for`.

Once you have a clean division like this, hopefully your error will disappear!

**Update**

I see there's still some overlap in paths (the initial `users POST /users(.:format) users/registrations#create` in your `rake routes` output, though this is POST rather than PUT, so doesn't *seem* like it should be a problem for the PUT (unless you're using the associated `users_path` helper in a different context). Instead, it would conflict with the later mapping to `POST /users(.:format) users#create`. This overlap is due to the `post '/users', :to => 'users/registrations#create'` in your `devise_for`. However, is there a reason you have this extra mapping?  It's equivalent to the `user_registration POST /club_users(.:format) users/registrations#create`, just `/users` instead of `/club_users`.  Could you remove it so there's no path overlap?  I'm concerned it's having an effect, though I'm guessing a bit without controller/view code.

By the way, I also use webrick in dev. and passenger in prod., and Rails 3.2.17, devise etc., though I'm using Ruby 1.9.3.  I don't see any obvious reason why they should be the cause of your problem in themselves.  It's more likely to be the routing setup.

Comment: Hi Tim, Sorry for late reply only got time for this today. So I have taken on board your comments and adjusted my routes file. Im still having the same issue. Ive updated my original post with my current setup.

Comment: No problem.  That's weird.  Updated answer.